# Google Apps Script - For Loop Print Single Row Multiple Time

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, sourceforge-appscript

```
function sendMail() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Pending Tasks");
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lr-1,10).getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i<range.filter(String).length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j<range[i].filter(String).length; j++){
      var timestamp = range[i][0];
      
       
      Logger.log(range[i],[j]);
    
    }
  }
  
}
```

In the below code it prints the same row 10 times because I have selected 10 columns in range, if I select 2 columns it prints 2 rows at a time.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74652361/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are attempting to iterate all non-blank values in a sheet. The `for` loops will not work correctly because the `condition` expressions will get the wrong columns in all rows.

Another issue is with `Logger.log(range[i],[j]);` that will log two values: the full row followed by an array that contains a running integer.

Use `forEach()`, like this:

```js
function sendMail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const values = ss.getRange('Pending Tasks!A2:J').getValues();
  values.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
    const timestamp = row[0];
    row.forEach((value, columnIndex) => {
      if (value !== '') {
        console.log({ 'timestamp': timestamp, 'value': value, 'row': rowIndex + 1, 'column': columnIndex + 1 });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: it has a same as mine coding has

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendMail() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Pending Tasks");
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lr-1,10).getValues();
  var range2 = sheet.getRange(2,1,lr-1,1).getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i<range2.filter(String).length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j<range2[i].filter(String).length; j++){ 
      var name = range[i][9];
      if(name == "Nitish"){
      Logger.log(range[i],[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```

it is done by using another range.

Comment: If this is an answer, please explain how it solves the question you asked. If this is supplemental information to the question, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74652361/edit) your question and add it there.